# Change only specific column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I read a .csv file with the following column names:

```
mycolnames <- c("ID", "RECORDE.CODE" ,"X...." ,"X.....1", "X.....2" ,"X.....3", "Q14", "Q15.16", "Q17.18", "Q19",
"Q20" ,"Q21...." ,"Q22....", "Q23" ,"Q24", "Q25" ,"Q26", "Q27", "Q28" ,"Q29",
"Q30" ,"Q31" ,"Q32", "Q33" ,"Q34" ,"Q35" ,"Q36", "Q37", "Q38", "Q39",
"Q40" ,"Q41" ,"Q42" ,"Q43", "Q44", "Q45" ,"Q46", "Q47", "Q48" ,"Q48.1",
"Q50" ,"Q51", "Q52" ,"Q53.73" ,"X......A", "X......B", "Q21","Q22.A" ,"Q22.B")
```

I want to change the names only for specific columns (all the columns that don't start with Q).
I can rename them one by one, but I can’t manage to change them all in one (long) command.

Would love to get any idea for that.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if `data` is your data set and `newnames` is the new names vector, so something like this should work

```
colnames(data)[!grepl("^Q", colnames(data))] <- newnames
```